# php gettext ignores locale

Tags: php, locale, gettext

I have a very strange problem: I am using a podcast solution called "Podcast Generator" (podcastgenerator.net), and installed on one server the gettext based translation is working perfect (www.fegertest.de/podcasts), while on the other server it simply won't translate (www.feg-erlangen.de/podcasts).

I checked already the following things:

- Locale is correctly configured in configuration file
- gettext is installed on both servers
- locale de_DE of browser is available
- php version is 7 on both servers
- locale is correctly set in the code

```
$locale="de_DE";
if (!ini_get('safe_mode')) 
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain($domain, LOCALE_DIR);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $encoding); //encoding
textdomain($domain);
```

I have no idea what else could be the reason for it... Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

The locale "de_DE" has to be installed on the *server*. Run "locale -a grep de_DE" to verify that.

Besides, the environment variable `LC_ALL` may not be the right one to set. Set `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, and `LC_MESSAGES` as well. See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gettext.git/tree/gettext-runtime/ABOUT-NLS and read the section "1.2 Using This Package" that explains the exact meaning of the various environment variables in great detail.